# How to plot a mean monthly data from a daily time series

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a series data of daily rainfall from Jan-01-1976 up to Dec-31-2001 for both predicted and observed. And what i want to plot them into a graph of mean monthly from Jan-Feb...Dec. Can you tell me how to do it in Excel or Matlab ? Thank you very much !

Daily data
[image: This photo represents daily of predicted and observed]

And i want it to be like this:

[image: A sample of mean monthly data]

Comment: Do you have daily values? Are there two columns, one with date and one with rainfall? Can you provide a sample of the data set? Btw: How is it possible to predict negative precipitation? Seems like the meteorologist have been smoking something... =P

Comment: Also, can you post a few lines of your data as an example?  Assuming the dates are in the format you mention:  In Excel, you can create a new "month" column containing the first three characters from your date (use the left command) and then create a pivot chart with your month column as the "axis" and your rainfall columns as the "values" (summarizing by average).

Comment: Data such as: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By5tEg03EXCpRzN4OUVCMHgtWEE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I didn't see any dates in that file, only predicted and observed values

Comment: Sorry, I just modified. Please check it again, Thank for your support

Answer (score 1):

First you will need to find which month each date falls upon. Judging by your linked data, you can do something simple but (i think) slow:

```
for i = 1:last_index
    % use automatic date overflow of datevec() func
    ldate = datevec(datenum(1976, 1, i))
    month = ldate(2);
```

From that point you can assign observed and predicted data to months by associating each month with its respective index, i.e. January = 1, February = 2 etc.

After that, you can plot vertical bars for each month with the `bar()` function.

Edit: ok, here's some more code. I assume your data is in the form `predicted observed`, and resides in a vector called `rainData`.

```
% create matrix for per-month data
monthlyData = zeros(12, 2);
% create matrix for month occurences
months = zeros(12, 1);

for i = 1:length(rainData)
    % use automatic date overflow of datevec() func
    ldate = datevec(datenum(1976, 1, i))
    month = ldate(2);

    % update month occurences
    months(month) = months(month) + 1;

    % update observed sum 
    monthlyData(month, :) = monthData(month, :) + rainData(i, :);
end

% extract means for each month
% dividing the sum of rain values for each month with the month's occurences
for i = 1:12
    monthlyData(i, :) = monthlyData(i, :) / months(i);
end
```

At that point monthlyData is 12x2 array where each row corresponds to a month and has the form of `[predictedValue observedValue]`. Use `bar(monthlyData)` to plot a histogram-like figure.

Also, check out the [Matrices and Arrays Tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html) if you have trouble understanding the indexing above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I am not good in Matlab then  very hard to understand this code, but if you can rewrite again that could be better for me to follow. Or even do it in Excel if you can.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use excel.
The main idea is to use the data index as the day field in datenum structure. From there, `datevec()` will handle overflows, i.e. `datevec(datenum(1976, 1, 366))` will evaluate to 1977-1-1-0-0, letting you grab the month field automatically.

I will post some more code as a starting point in a few minutes.

Comment: Dear VHarisop!I run the code that you provided but it is till displacing errors such as it could not identifies this function of "monthlyData(month,:)". Can you please take time for this code again? Thank so much !